# LINQ distinct from query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

i have simple code from two class:

```
    public class Contact
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }


    public class CallLog
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public bool Incoming { get; set; }
        public DateTime When { get; set; }
    }
```

Now In two class i have static method: **SampleData()**, where i get all data from source (SQL Server - return List);

my code:

```
List<Contact> contacts = Contact.SampleData();
List<CallLog> callLogs = CallLog.SampleData();
```

now I would get numbers where Incomming = true and Incomming = false (group by contact.Number) and telephone number owner.

I have write this code:

```
var query = from contact in contacts
                        join callLog in callLogs on contact.Phone equals callLog.Number
                        group callLog by callLog.Number into g
                        select new
                        {
                            owner = Contact.SampleData().Where(c => c.Phone == g.Key).Take(1),
                            number = g.Key,
                            inCommingCall = callLogs.Where( c => c.Number == g.Key && c.Incoming == true).Count(),
                            outGoingCall = callLogs.Where( c=> c.Number == g.Key && c.Incoming == false).Count()
                        };
            foreach (var q in query)
            {
                foreach (var c in q.owner) Console.Write("owner = {0}, ", c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName);
                Console.WriteLine("number = {0}, in = {1}, out = {2}", q.number, q.inCommingCall, q.outGoingCall);
            }
```

It's look good?

better query:

```
var query = from contact in contacts
                        join callLog in callLogs on contact.Phone equals callLog.Number
                        group contact by new {contact.FirstName, contact.LastName, contact.Phone} into g
                        select new
                        {
                            owner = g.Key.FirstName + " " + g.Key.LastName,
                            inComming = callLogs.Where(c=>c.Number == g.Key.Phone && c.Incoming == true).Count(),
                            outGoing = callLogs.Where(c=>c.Number == g.Key.Phone && c.Incoming == false).Count()
```

Comment: show the definition of ``SampleData()``

Comment: What exactly is your question ? Do you want numbers where `incomming = true` ?? and what is the link between `CallLog` and `Contact` ?

Comment: Contact.Phone = CallLog.Number
Yes, I want where incoming = true and incoming = false.
SampleDate return simpleList, which return List<Contact> and List<CallLog>

Answer (score 1):

```
var callsByContact = contacts.GroupJoin(callLogs, 
    c => c.Phone, 
    l => l.Number,
    (c, calls) => new { 
        Contact = c, 
        IncomingCalls = calls.Where(x => x.Incoming).ToList(), 
        OutgoingCalls = calls.Where(x => !x.Incoming).ToList()
    });
```

This should organise your call records by `Number` and then give you a list of all incoming/outgoing calls for that particular number.

Comment: but I would get more owner name, which exist in List<Contact> (CallLog.Number = Contact.Phone)

Comment: @cniak see update, you can use `GroupJoin` for that.